# How to add background color to label names of barplots using seaborn / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am currently trying to change the background color of my labels in a barplot.
I'm interested if this is somehow possible with seaborn.

I've already read the documentation and searched on stackoverflow but I could not find a solution.

```py
"""
pal is the color palette I am using for my plot 
"""
imported = pd.read_csv("""FILENAME.csv""", sep=";")
    data = imported.filter(items=column_names)

    data.columns = new_names

    for index, row in data.iterrows():

        again_new_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':row.index, 'value':row.values})

        sns.set(style="whitegrid")
        ax = sns.barplot(x='value', y='name', data=again_new_df, palette=pal)
        ax.set(xlabel='common xlabel', ylabel='common ylabel')
        plt.xlim(0, 1)
        plt.show()
        break
```

I've created two plots in PowerPoint just for demonstration purpose so my problem is clear:

"My current plot":

[image: current_plot]

This is how the plot should look like:

[image: new_plot]

Comment: [ax.axvline()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html)  [ax.text()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)

Comment: would it be an acceptable solution to simply put the label on the bar?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am transferring some plots from an R script to Python so they have to look as identical as possible :/ 
Or did i misunderstand your comment? @Gio :)

Comment: @Adrian not sure if you misunderstood it or not. What I mean is: Is it a requirement that the color bar spans to the left of the Y axis? Because you could let the bar be as it is (spanning from zero onward) and simply put the column label on the bar, without extending it to the left of the axis